# Share permission for read file in child proccess without close the handle, using FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE

Tags: c, winapi

I' m creating a handle to file for delete on close, with permission for read.
I need without close the handle (because it will deleted the file) create a process that can read the file.

This is my implementation: I create a file, and without close I try open the file with notepad, but it not can. How I can solve this. I imagine that I can be something in the parameters of CreateProcess, but I don't have idea.

Please help.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;
    HANDLE hFile;
    TCHAR text[] = "This is a text";
    DWORD dwWrited;

    hFile = CreateFile(
    "data.txt",
    GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    NULL,
    CREATE_ALWAYS,
    FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE
    ,NULL
    );

    WriteFile(hFile, text, sizeof(text), &dwWrited, NULL);
    FlushFileBuffers(hFile);

    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    CCreateProcess(TEXT("C:\\Windows\\System32\\Cmd.exe"),
              TEXT("/C \"Notepad.exe data.txt\""),
              NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
              NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);


    puts("Press a key for close the file");
    getchar();
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: perhaps you need an absolute path to the data.txt file in your notepad command line, in case the new process has a different current working directory.

Comment: Possibly related, why not just spawn Notepad.exe directly rather than through cmd.exe?

Answer (score 5):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flag says:

> If there are existing open handles to a file, the call fails unless they were all opened with the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` share mode.
>
> Subsequent open requests for the file fail, unless the `FILE_SHARE_DELET`E share mode is specified.

Notepad does not open the file with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`, so it fails to open the file with `ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION` ("The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.").

Since you cannot rewrite Notepad, the only way to solve your problem is to not use the `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` flag, or use a different program besides Notepad which opens the file with the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` share mode.